# Incorrect results by valgrind with --trace-children=yes

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I am not able to figure out how to get memleaks detected in multiprocess scenarios, where in child process is launched by parent.

With this command I see very strange behaviours

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --log-file=valgrind.log ./parent
```

If there is a `mem leak in both parent & child`, I see generated `valgrind.log` has leak detected for parent only.
However if there is `mem leak only in child` generated reports are correct.

Sample code reproducing this
https://github.com/shrkamat/valg

Comment: it should create separate log files for children.

Comment: I don't see any log file generated for child process. I see only valgrind.log what will be the name of log for child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear form the documentation now!

--log-file=
Specifies that Valgrind should send all of its messages to the specified file. If the file name is empty, it causes an abort. There are three special format specifiers that can be used in the file name.
%p is replaced with the current process ID. This is very useful for program that invoke multiple processes. WARNING: If you use --trace-children=yes and your program invokes multiple processes OR your program forks without calling exec afterwards, and you don't use this specifier (or the %q specifier below), the Valgrind output from all those processes will go into one file, possibly jumbled up, and possibly incomplete.

Comment: if it goes it one file, it should prefix lines with  the process id, something like `===pid===`.  you should be able to grep there as well.